# Processing multiple submit buttons in JSP

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp that shows me a list of students from base. For each student I want 2 buttons - Edit and Delete. On Edit click the request should be redirected to my servlet-controller and a new jsp for editing selected student's data is opened. On Delete click a delete request for selected student is sent to controler. Now it looks like this:

```
<%@page import="socnet2.Student"%>
<!-- class Student emulates real student -->
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:useBean class="socnet2.DAO" id="dao" scope="request"></jsp:useBean>
<p><b>List of all students:</b></p>
<form action="/JSP1/Controler" method="POST">

            <jsp:scriptlet>
        for (Student s : dao.getAllStudents()) {
            </jsp:scriptlet>
            <p> <jsp:expression> s.getName() + " " + s.getSurname()</jsp:expression></p>
            <input type="submit" name="Edit" value="Edit" />
            <input type="submit" name="Delete" value ="Delete"/>
            <jsp:scriptlet>
        }
            </jsp:scriptlet>

    </form>
</body>
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to connect my students with buttons in a way that when request is sent to contoller it is known which button was clicked and what student was selected. I understand I need some unique id for each student, but don't know how to create it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that `Student` already have some kind of ID. Let's say for example that it has `private String id` and appropriate getter `public String getId()`.

In this case you just should use this ID when generating name of submit buttons:

```
       <input type="submit" name="Edit_<%=s.getId()%>" value="Edit" />
        <input type="submit" name="Delete_<%=s.getId()%>" value ="Delete"/>
```

Now you can distinguish between students on server side. 
Alternatively you can create separate form for each student and give to each form its unique URL:

`<form method="post" url="http://myhost/myapp/students/<%s.getId()%>">`

Comment: Thanks for the idea.The matter is I don't have a unique ID for a Student inside a class, because class Student is only somekind wrapper and in base exist only big table USERS with different roles for each user.So I used simple integer counter to add. I change the code above as you suggested and tried such   <jsp:scriptlet>
            int counter = 0;  
ArrayList<Student> students = dao.getAllStudents();
session.setAttribute("students", students);
           for (Student s : dao.getAllStudents()) {
            </jsp:scriptlet> to not to double the request. But now <jsp:scriptlet> is bad

Comment: I mean request to DB. But now netbeans says that  <jsp:scriptlet> is unterminated